# not changing the text color inputted from user

Tags: python, colors, prompt-toolkit, python-prompt-toolkit

i want to change the prompt color to red and the inputted color to blue but it is not working. I am using prompt-toolkit for this purpose

```
prompt_style = styles.Style.from_dict({
    'input_prompt': 'fg:yellow',
    'input' : 'fg:blue',
    'prompt':'fg:red'
})
command = session.prompt(">>>>",style=prompt_style)
```

it changes the color of `>>>>` to red but anything else does makes any change to the prompt. can you tell me how to change the text inputted by user to blue also.

Comment: I meet this problem too, have you already fixed this?